# Why does my camera fail to open when being run on my Android EAS build?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, expo-camera

My EAS app crashes after taking a photo on Android. The user takes a photo but after attempting to upload it to the app itself, the app crashes. This doesn't happen on iOS, it appears to just be an Android issue.

Below is my code:

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'; 
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'; 

const [ image1, setImage1 ] = useState(null); 

const takeImage = async ()=>{ 

const { granted } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync() 

if(granted){ 
   let data = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ 
     mediaTypes:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
     allowsEditing: false,
     aspect:[1,1],
     quality:0.5,
     base64: true,
     doNotSave: true
}) 

    console.log(data.base64) 

   if (!data.cancelled){
      setImage1({"uri": data.uri, "raw_data": data.base64}); 
  }

      } 
return;

if (granted === false ){
    Alert.alert(i18n.t('noPermission'))
  }
  console.log('There is no permission')


<View style = {styles.centerAlignment}>
      <View style = {styles.pictureAlignment}>
        {image1 && <Image source={{uri:`data:image/jpg;base64,${image1.raw_data}`}} style = {styles.phoneImage}/>}
      </View>
    
      <View style = {styles.centerAlignment}>         
        <TouchableOpacity
           onPress = { takeImage }
           style = {styles.button2}
        >
          <Text style = {styles.photoText}>{i18n.t('pho1')}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

</View>
```

Comment: what are you getting on console??

Comment: In short, console does not log anything.


Long run of things: 

I click the camera, it opens, my console reports I am now running my app in the background. I take a photo, I accept the photo, it goes to send me back to my app, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, and [this](https://forums.expo.dev/t/barcodescanner-crashes-standalone-but-not-on-dev/59305/4) thread helped me. My app worked fine with the "regular" build method, but crashed when using EAS.

I was using expo-camera for reading barcodes, and adding `expo-barcode-scanner` to my `package.json` solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I created a snack example that's takes a shot and upload it, and it's working perfectly, please try it and let me know :

https://snack.expo.dev/@adgogo/camera

it's working perfectly, here's a screen from it :

[image]

I probably thing it's a problem in your device.

Comment: The expo go app keeps crashing on Android

Comment: @shyguy189540 reboot your device then, it's probably a device problem not from the code, and run it from your device

Comment: I restarted my device, uninstalled and reinstalled Expo Go, and the app continues to crash when trying to boot that snack

Comment: As a side note tho, I have built and used the camera on the Expo-Go app and in a snack independently; this issue seems to be isolated to EAS

Comment: @shyguy189540 if it's an EAS problem it should give you a console error

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case :')

Should it be in my EAS logs on the expo website, or on my internal log?

Comment: I attempted to add your fix into my app. This still causes the app to crash